# How to type an old style greek phrase in text mode?

Tags: font-encodings, greek

I need to type an greek phrase: Let no one untrained in geometry enter. Jusk like

- http://home.wlu.edu/~mahonj/Greeklanguage.htm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_phrases

I hope it looks like the old style as much as possible.

[image]

I have tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\textgreek{'agewm`etrhtos mhde`is e'is'itw}
\end{document}
```

The result is not satisfying.

[image]

The main problems are

- I need `\epsilon`, but get a `\varepsilon`
- There are symbols with comma above it, how to type that?
- There are differences between the fonts, e.g. `\mu`

## UPDATE

Thanks to @Sverre, omma problem is solved. Except `\epsilon` problem, I still think there are font problems. My latex result is a little slim, and some detail is different, e.g. the tail of the `\mu`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\textgreek{>agewm`etrhtos mhde`is e>is'itw}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## UPDATE

The first picture missed a letter $\tau$, and the actual sculpture looks like this

[image]

with all letters captialized. So I need not bother to persuit any effect. Anyway, this question is fruitful, leading to `LGR` and `GFS Philostratos` solutions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'There are differences between the fonts'? I wonder if you are expecting to see the same glyphs as in math mode: 'real' Greek doesn't use the same font shapes as the 'Greek' letters used for maths.

Comment: @JosephWright I use `\eta` to refer the letter, not the specific font.

Comment: The epsilon in your LaTeX output looks like a perfectly normal epsilon to me.

Comment: @Sverre I just want the old style effect.

Comment: @MartinWang Like I said, I'm not sure what you mean by 'there are differences between the fonts': what is being compared with what?

Comment: To get the spiritus lenis, type ``\>``, e.g. ``\>agewm`etrhtos mhde'is e\>is`itw``.

Comment: @JosephWright, OK, difference on `\mu` is more obvious

Comment: What exactly is the "old style effect" for a miniscule epsilon character? In the sample you provide, I see a regular miniscule epsilon when it has an accent, but a majuscule type epsilon when it doesn't have an accent. Is that really the effect you're after?

Comment: @Sverre, there are two variations of `\epsilon` in the old style phrase, I just get one.

Comment: GFS Philostratos, from the Greek Font Society (http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/pages/en_typefaces19th.html), looks closer to the typeface in the image.  I don’t know whether anyone has made support files for using it with `pdftex`, but you can use it with `luatex` or `xetex`.

Comment: Your first image appears to be missing a *tau* in αγεωμετρητος.

Comment: It also has the wrong accent for the the epsilon in the same word.  (As far as I [clearly only sort of] know, the grave accent can only appear on the last syllable.)  See Thérèse's answer for the correct spelling.

Comment: The epsilon in two variants is a clear error; in both places either the lunate glyph or the non lunate one should be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is less an answer than a response to requests in the comments.  If the point is to make the Greek appear to be on the old side, there are many possibilities opened up by `lualatex` and `xetex`, which can use any unicode-encoded TrueType or OpenType font.  Here are four specimens:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFS Philostratos}% a 19th-century antiqua
\newfontface\milan{Avdira}[% http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/
  Ligatures=Rare]
\newfontface\compl{GFS Complutum}% 16th century
\newfontface\ign{GFS Ignacio}% because there were no minuscules in Plato’s day
\begin{document}
\centering
% GFS Philostratos; I’d reduce the linespread
ἀγεωμέτρητος\\
μηδεὶς εἰσίτω

\bigskip

\linespread{1.10344}
% Avdira
\milan ἀγεωμέτρητος\\
μηδεὶς εἰσίτω

\bigskip

% GFS Complutum
\compl ἀγεωμέτρητος\\
μηδεὶς εἰσίτω

\bigskip

% GFS Ignacio
\ign ΑΓΕΩΜΕΤΡΗΤΟΣ\\
ΜΗΔΕΙΣ ΕΙΣΙΤΩ
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the source above]

Comment: You are missing the tau (τ) in ἀγεωμὲτρητος. (It does not bode well for your entry to the Academy ;)

Comment: @jon Silly me, I was thinking too much about reproducing the effect of the OP’s image and forgot the meaning.  Will fix.

Comment: No worries.  Cheers!

Comment: @jon Wrong accent on the epsilon, too.  But what can you expect from a member of the Lyceum?

Comment: Haha.  Oops! And the rules for the grave accent is probably the easiest one to remember....

Answer (score 5):

To get the spiritus lenis, type `\>`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\textgreek{\>agewm`etrhtos mhde'is e\>is`itw}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't really understand what you mean by your other questions.

As a friendly tip, try googling before posting a question on TeX.sx. I googled "lgr latex", and the first hit provides a one-page manual explaining how to type Greek with the LGR encoding.

Comment: Thanks. but there is only one type of `\epsilon` in your answer regardless of the accent.

Comment: +1 You're the only one to have the correct quote with “ἀγεωμὲτρητος”. ;-) The motto over the entrance of the Academy in Athens, for those who don't know: *Do not enter if you know no geometry*.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing between `ui` and `uv` font shapes will change the appearance of ε. Also, this seems to work without `LGR` if you use the `babel` package with the `polutonikogreek` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand*{\uishape}{\fontshape{ui}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textui}{\uishape}
\newcommand*{\uvshape}{\fontshape{uv}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textuv}{\uvshape}

\newcommand{\grk}[1]{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}\fontshape{ui}\selectfont #1\selectlanguage{english}}
\begin{document}
\centering
\grk{>agewm\textuv{`e}trhtos\\ mhde`is\\ e>is'itw}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit:
Another option using `gfsdidot`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gfsdidot}
\begin{document}
\centering
\selectlanguage{greek}\selectfont 
>ag\textui{e}wm`etrhtos\\ mhd\textui{e}`is\\ \textui{e}>is'itw
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You solved one problem, but the default LGR effect seems better.

Comment: What effect are you referring to? The typeface?

Comment: maybe. If LGR is just a little different, your result is totally another font. For example, the `\alpha`. It's just too formal.

Comment: I've added an alternative. Finding just the right typeface depends on your personal preference, but the variation on epsilon is something you can select by choosing the appropriate `fontshape`.

Comment: Thanks, it's almost done. Can you use `GFS Philostratos` font in your example? http://www.greekfontsociety.gr/GFS_PHILOSTRATOS.zip

Comment: @MartinWang Not very easily. `GFS Philostratos` is available as an open type font, but a TeX compatible version has not been released. In order to use `GFS Philostratos` you would either need to make the `.otf` work with `pdflatex`, or switch to `XeLaTeX` and deal with encoding issues. Neither of these are straightforward.

Comment: You are missing the *tau* (τ) in ἀγεωμὲτρητος.  (It does not bode well for your entry to the Academy ;)

Comment: @jon Compare my figure to the OP's first figure (not from the MWE). Academicians must also have an eye for detail ;)

Comment: Indeed, but his image is grammatically incorrect in two ways. (I didn't even notice the second one at first!)  You need a 't' in the word *ageometretos* (somewhat like "non-geometer").  And the accent over the epsilon should be acute, not grave (i.e., é, not è).

Comment: Doh! I guess I should have checked the wikipedia link.

Comment: I've corrected the spelling. I presume that's what the downvotes were for. Geez, forgive me for trying to reproduce what the OP originally posted as their desired outcome.

Comment: "switch to XeLaTeX and deal with encoding issues"; Using UTF-8 input encoding, there is absolutely nothing to "deal with" as shown in Thérèses answer.

Comment: @morbusg Of course that's true if you are able to input the language directly. What I meant was you would not be able to use the same input method, e.g., `>a` to get the letter ἀ.