# Greek text on texlive is broken, linux mint

Tags: texlive, font-encodings, greek, xgreek

I want to output Greek fonts using ascii encoding (something like `\greektext{hoi pol'oi}`) because it's much more convenient. This used to work flawlessly.

The old answers given on StackExchange don't work for me. I've tried `greek-fontenc` and got the usual (NFSS system not set up correctly). `lgreek` also didn't work. `babel` doesn't seem to be an option, unless one of you knows how to get ascii encoding.

Does anyone have a *current* working example with texlive encoding Greek fonts in ascii? I'm using texlive, so no miktex specific stuff please.

Comment: I hate this type of question. You are leaving all the work to us. Why don't you provide a small example that "used to work" and give at least a bit info what doesn't work for you now?

Comment: link to "old answers" ? You might help people to help by showing a complete small document that you think used to work and now doesn't.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348052/how-to-type-greek-in-latex-environment

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to work it out. Either you have something working or not. I'd like a code example from someone who has working code. The only restriction is that I'm using texlive because that's what came standard with my Linux distribution. I suppose it's an option to rip out texlive and install miktex. That's also an acceptable answer, if that's the best solution.

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question. \greektext still works fine and if it is broken for you you will have to give more info.

Comment: Can you post the header from a working code example? It will be instructive for me to run it on my systems. As I mentioned, it could just be my installation of texlive that's broken.

Comment: Egreg's answer to the question you link works fine in my TeXLive 2016.

Comment: I won't. If you want help from me improve your question first.

Comment: I'm sure Egreg's code does, but it doesn't use ascii encoding. I guess that I was really referring to the question by RestlessC0bra. Let's try the answer by Sverre in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215701/how-to-type-an-old-style-greek-phrase-in-text-mode . On my linux distro, latex gives the error "Corrupted NFSS tables \textgreek ...". I suppose that's progress. Still, my installation is what comes with the distro. Sverre's code fails on linux and won't even return on Windows miktex. I'm sure it worked in the past. I'm just looking to fix the present.

Comment: Sverre may have a typo there, for the breathings need not be escaped. Replacing `\>` by `>` works fine, as does using `babel` with the `greek` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255003/127829) and in Sverre's code example referenced above. andreibarbaros, you are a winner!! As per his suggestion:

```
tlmgr install cbfonts cbfonts-fd greek-fontenc textgreek babel-greek
```

The important packages are cbfonts & cbfonts-fd[most important]. The others are things I installed along the way and am too lazy to uninstall to confirm their irrelevance.